# nginx reversre proxy not returning the correct app endpoint

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am installing a nginx reverse proxy along with a few applications (netdata, filebrowser, etc) on a docker compose file.

my idea is from computers outside of my network to call an url like `http://netdata.myserver.com` and point to netdata. At the moment it works when I do `http://myserver.com:19999/` (The end goal is to remove the ports for subdomains).

I have the next configuration in the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.com # thats not the ip, but you get the idea
```

So i have netdata, filebrowser and nginx on the docker compose file, like the next:

```
version: '3'
services:
  netdata:
    image: netdata/netdata
    ports:
      - 19999:19999
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
  filebrowser:
    image: filebrowser/filebrowser
    user: 501:501
    ports:
      - 20001:80
    volumes:
      - volumes and things go here
    restart: unless-stopped

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=myserver.com
```

and then in the `default.conf` I have the next configuration

```
server {
    server_name netdata.myserver.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://netdata:19999;
       }
    listen 80;
}
```

But it is not working as expected, when i go to `http://netdata.myserver.com` i get a "cant reach this site" but, if i go to `http://myserver.com` it does return netdata for me; which I do not understand why either.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a correct DNS entry set up for the `netdata` host name?  Something in your `/etc/hosts` file would need to be replicated on every client machine, and that's not a great way to go; I'd delete that entry.  If you can connect to your server's IP address on port 80 and get your site, then your Docker configuration is correct, and it's all going to be networking and DNS setup from there; that's beyond the programming-oriented scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze ouuu yeah, that makes sense; i thought it will work as normal, that it will got to the domain and then look to the subdomain.  then with your comment i remembered that you have to specify the `A` record on the DNS for the subdomain too, completly forgot. ‍♂️.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be a couple of problems here. First, if you expect to be host two name-based virtual hosts behind Nginx, you'll need two `server` blocks (one for each). So your `default.conf` file should probably look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://filebrowser:2001
       }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name netdata.myserver.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://netdata:19999;
       }
}
```

You will also need to be able to resolve both host names, which means
you're missing an entry from your example `hosts` file. You would need
something like:

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.com netdata.myserver.com
```

With this configuration, a request for anything *other* than
`netdata.myserver.com` would get served by your `filebrowser`
container. Requests for `netdata.myserver.com` would get served by the
`netdata` container.

I've put together a runnable example
[here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-70229400) if that helps.
That would require a local `hosts` file that looks something like:

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.com netdata.myserver.com
```

Comment: Yes it is exaclty this, I was completly missing the entries in the hostfile for the subdomains. Thanks.